# Change the data of database dynamically without changing the frame in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am a doing a project on Exam Suit in Netbeans swing java application. I have done all my work like login page, sign up page etc etc. But the main problem stick with exam page. I have inserted all the question and there choices with answer(not shown) in a database. I have designed one frame, 1 label for question and three radio buttons for choices and an OK button to select the choices and NEXT button to goto next question. I can easily get the data from database of only one row. But to get the other question I should keep the code in NEXT button, but this can be done only one time. I just want to change the data from table dynamically on click of NEXT button. I am unable to do this, Please help me. Thank You.....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest that you write a small piece of code that illustrates what you are trying to do. This will help you ask a more clear question that will attract the answer you are looking for.

Comment: If the questions have some kind sequence number in the database, you could get the current sequence and request the next from the database until no results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program acesses a database, I assume that you are using `ResultSet` from JDBC. You need to call [`ResultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) each time the user clicks on the "Next" button. As long as you keep a reference to the `ResultSet`, you can call this method until you reach the end of the data set.